# Symbolizing by color names in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, dynamic

I have a shapefile with two fields, lets call them shape and color. I want to symbolize each point based on both of those fields. Each field is stored as a string. Example: "Square, Blue". I want to symbolize each point with the shape listed in shape, and the color listed in color. So my example would show up as a blue square. I have tried symbolizing by categories: unique values, many fields, but I have too many possible combinations to do this. I can manually choose a shape for each "shape" field, but I would like it to dynamically change the color based on the "color" field

Comment: I would replace points by simple geometry polygons with size suitable for scale map, e.g. Square, circle, star and symbolised them by color. Relatively easy thing to do, I'd start with buffer and modified ones that are not circle

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do this without some programming.  Most likely ArcObjects.  The only symbology parameters you can set with fields seems to be Size and Rotation.

[image]

Alternatively, you could try creating a style for each possible combination (though you indicated that there were too many).  You'd have to merge your two fields into one as your value field:

[image]